# Spring MVC Test: Set Jackson Default View Inclusion

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to set to set the Jackson mapper property of "default view inclusion" true in my Spring MVC test. Per [these release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.2-Release-Notes), I have this in my `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion=true
```

This works when I run my application, but not when I run my test. What's the best way to do the same for my test?

**Update**

One approach I tried was to include my config file in the test.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTest.Config.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

I can see in the logs that this loads my `application.properties`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    @Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(translationsRessource)
        .setControllerAdvice(new ControllerExceptionHandler())
        .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter())
        .build();
}

private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, true);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return converter;
}
```